# AWS Lex Access Denied after lambda redeployed. Wrong default IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I created an AWS Lex bot and added an intent recently. Then I uploaded a simple AWS Lambda, which has an administrator access (I will lower it later, no worries) and then also added some trusted entities:

Trusted entities

- The identity provider(s) apigateway.amazonaws.com
- The identity provider(s) lambda.amazonaws.com
- The identity provider(s) events.amazonaws.com
- The identity provider(s) lex.amazonaws.com

Then I added the lambda function to the intent and build the bot, start testing it. It worked just fine.
Next step was (in 10 minutes) to update the lambda function (test new functionality). I added a new version and went back to AWS Lex and start writing messages and the following error message came up:

An error has occurred: Access denied while invoking lambda function arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:99999999999:function:lex-test from arn:aws:lex:us-east-1:888888888:intent:test:3. Please check the policy on this function.

First, I thought it was my mistake, and started looking into the problem, but then, I noticed the **AWSServiceRoleForLexBots** role's policy is not right.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "polly:SynthesizeSpeech"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

I can't change it because *"This service-linked role cannot be modified in IAM. You can modify this role from the AWS service that depends on this role."*
If I click through every intent again and remove the lambda function and then add it again and then build and publish it, it will work until the next update.

However, this is a nightmare. Do you have any idea how could I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Using AWS CLI try this:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name lex-test --statement-id chatbot-fulfillment --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --principal "lex.amazonaws.com"
```

And take a look: [Using Resource-Based Policies for AWS Lambda (Lambda Function Policies)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html)

Comment: This will work, but it has the same issue,  you have to run it each time you deploy an updated lambda function. You could script this code to run on every deploy. I haven't found another workaround for this. For me, I am using [zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) with lex/lambda and use it's local callback feature to add the function policy each update. Kinda lame, but it works.

Comment: Or via boto3:    response=lambda.client.add_permission(FunctionName=fn,StatementId='unique123',Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',Principal='lex.amazonaws.com')